# Here.com Destination Weather API returns "Forbidden" "These credentials do not authorize access"

Tags: here-api, weather-api

Using the Here.com Freemium account, previously I was using the [example here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/auto_weather/weather-forecast-7days-simple) with my own API Key and some modifications to get the 7 day forecast. Based on this command, I had some code running in my back-end server every 2h collecting data, which ran for about a week without problems. I have not touched the code since then.

After a week, it stopped working.

Now, even when I generate a new API key, and use the same command, I get the following return data in Postman:

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

Is my account restricted? It doesn't say anything about it in my Project page:
[image]

Comment: Update: Even using an API key from a different account, I get the same error. Is the service down or something?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing anything, suddenly it started working again, and on Oct. 1st.

I suspected I was being throttled, but when I tried using the service on a separate account, that also didn't work. So it seems likely the service was down. I wish there was some news page that posted what the status was?...

Answer (score 0):

On developer.here.com you can look up the status of the services. I did this and don't see a reported problem for the Weather API for the last days.

My suggestion is that you missed to verify your email address after registering for your account. You still can do this at any time through clicking on the link that you received in an email from developer portal after your registration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It started working again without doing anything, so I guess this was not the root cause. Can you post the page where the status' are written?